# Inner product defined on a Vector Field on Complex Numbers

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vector-fields, mathematics, linear-algebra

I have a homework problem that seems wrong. Previous to the problem we showed that the inner product of a vector space $V$ on the field $\mathbb{C}$ defined as
$$ \langle v,w \rangle = a^i(b^j)^*\delta_{ij} $$
where $a^i, b^j$ are the components of the vectors $v = a^i e_{i}$, $w = b^i e_{i}$ satisfy the inner product space axioms. Namely
\begin{align*}
&\cdot \langle v,w \rangle = \langle w,v \rangle^* \\
&\cdot \langle au + bv,w \rangle = a\langle u,v \rangle + b\langle v,w \rangle \\
&\cdot \forall v\in \mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}, \quad  \langle v,v \rangle > 0 \\
&\cdot \langle 0,0 \rangle = 0
\end{align*}
The problem asks us to consider the inner product defined as:
$$ \langle a^i e_i, b^j e_j \rangle = b^i(a^j)^* \delta_{ij} $$
and explain why this does not define an inner product vector space.

It seems to me that it satisfies all the necessary axioms. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Probably it is just about on which slot of the inner product you put the anti-linearity (which is just convention; and most often physics and math conventions differ here). This can readily be seen from the fact that the last and the first expressions are the same except for the place where the complex conjugation is put, i.e. they are related by complex conjugation.

Comment: But your question belongs to Math SE---there is no physics involved here and no context given.